# Curvefit function - sinus function issue

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm quite new to Jupyter and Python and I'm trying to get a simple sinus fit.
On X, I have the degrees and on Y, the amplitude.
From one experiment, I got these points :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaOPx.png)

When I am trying to get a parameter defined with curvefit, I got this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ULuO.png)

Instead of this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpQyG.png)

How can I get the parameter a~0.035 with curvefit? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help! Sorry if this is not clear enough.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly it is a problem of not good initial values. I cannot help you because you didn't provide NUMERICAL data.